# Plotting the electron deflection between plates of the capacitor in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, physics

I want to plot the deflection of electron and all it shows no graph when i compile the program.
This is my code so far and the comments represent the SI units.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v=25300000 # m/s
E=1000 # V/m
d=10 # m
m=9*pow(10,-31) #kg 
q=1.6*pow(10,-19) # C

for i in range(0,d):
  y=(q*E*i*i)/(2*m*v*v)
  plt.plot(i,y)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can use `plot` to show individual points using `plt.plot(i,y,'o')`

Comment: I don't see an actual question in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a scatter plot. `plt.plot` plots a curve instead. To make a scatter plot, you group the x and y coordinates into lists and call `plt.scatter`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v=25300000 # m/s
E=1000 # V/m
d=10 # m
m=9*pow(10,-31) #kg 
q=1.6*pow(10,-19) # C

x_list = []
y_list = []

for i in range(0,d):
  y=(q*E*i*i)/(2*m*v*v)
  x_list.append(i)
  y_list.append(y)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.scatter(x_list, y_list)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

`plt.plot` requires more than one point (unless you specify a marker), so

```
plt.plot(i,y)
```

will not produce a graph when `i` and `y` are individual values, only if they are arrays or array-like objects. You can either replace this with `plt.scatter`,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v=25300000 # m/s
E=1000 # V/m
d=10 # m
m=9*pow(10,-31) #kg 
q=1.6*pow(10,-19) # C

for i in range(0,d):
  y=(q*E*i*i)/(2*m*v*v)
  plt.scatter(i,y)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

Which will give you

[image]

or to make a list of the `y` and `x` values,

```
y = []
x = []
for i in range(0, d):
    y.append((q*E*i*i)/(2*m*v*v))
     x.append(i)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Or, even better, make `x` and `y` numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
# ...
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = (q*E*x**2)/(2*m*v*v)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Either of which will give you

[image]